# Управление сервоприводом на ардуино

Tags: arduino

Этот экран можно подключить только к ардуино нано (tm1637)
а сервопривод на ардуино уно.(

К нано пробовал, не работает почему-то, хотя должно, вроде как, -

я не понимаю что делаю не так.

код:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo servol;

void setup() {

servo.attach (5); }

void loop() {

int potent = analogRead(5);

potent = map(potent, 0, 1024, 0, 180);

servol.write (potent);

delay(2); }
```

Ии, мне сначала нужно схему собрать и, пока что как-то вот так выглядит:
[image: собственно какая-то вот такая]
https://sun9-west.userapi.com/sun9-50/s/v1/ig2/Ooc7nimtsQHCbr2fmq5siEYjxwNmjbeOb6Hnhlu37YY_Dj9VBqHXpPu83HleSm2UnMzX79f_ElOWK0vZKG5a2PxT.jpg?size=1200x1600&quality=95&type=album

я уже хз как гуглить, мне нужно:

управление сервоприводом на ардуино

и чтобы скорость поворота отображалась на экране

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140626/discussion-on-question-by-samuel----).

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит питать силовую нагрузку от того же преобразователя, что и микроконтроллер. Силовая нагрузка заметно просаживает напряжение питания, и микроконтроллер может перезапускаться или впадать в "транс".

В Uno стоит достаточно мощный линейный регулятор (на ток 1 Ампер), так что его мощности хватает для питания сервопривода. Но в Nano из-за малых размеров платы столь же мощный регулятор не поставить - там стоит линейный регулятор с максимальным током 800 мА.